# How can I take advantage of my model associations in my view and controller in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, associations, foreign-key-relationship

I am new to Rails and am trying to set up my Models and was wondering how Rails handles associations.

I have a Quest object which "belongs_to" or references via foreign keys a number of other objects, including User and Content:

```
quest.user_id  
quest.a_different_name_id  #this is a foreign key to a Content object
```

these are both foreign keys referencing a User object and Content object respectively.

Both User and Content "has_many" Quests.

I understand that this setup allows me to do things like:

```
u = User.create #saves to database  
u.quests.build  #creates new Quest object with user id set to u.id
```

Can I do something in the opposite direction like:

```
form_for @quest do |f|
    f.text_field :a_user_attribute            #an attribute of a User object
    f.text_field :a_different_name_attribute  #an attribute of a Content object
```

where the form has text fields for the attributes of the objects which a Quest object references through its foreign keys as opposed to having a form for the actual foreign keys, so that when in the controller I have:

```
@quest = Quest.new(params[:quest])
```

Is Rails smart enough to "reach through" the model-defined foreign key relationships and populate and then save the User and Content objects and appropriately set the foreign keys in @quest to reference the newly created objects?

Can it do this even though the foreign key for the Content object has a different name than content_id?

Hope this makes sense... let me know if I am being unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you need with the Nested Attributes feature in Rails http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#nested-attributes

Check out the form helper for it here
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Basically you would need to do the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quests
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quests
  ...
end

class Quest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

then in the form you do the following:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  UserAttrA  : <%= f.text_field :a_user_attribute_a %>
  UserAttrB: <%= f.text_field :a_user_attribute_b %>
  <%= f.fields_for :quests do |qf| %>
    QuestAttrA  : <%= qf.text_field :a_quest_attribute_a %>
    QuestAttrB: <%= qf.text_field :a_quest_attribute_b %>
  <% end %>
  UserAttrC  : <%= f.text_field :a_user_attribute_c %>
  UserAttrD: <%= f.text_field :a_user_attribute_d %>
<% end %>
```

And your controller would work just like you have above.

Note that you can display User inputs before and/or after Quest inputs. Basically you can make the form in the view look how you want. But the semantics on the server will be need to be consistent.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The examples in the link you gave all have the relationship going the other way with a has_many or has_one as opposed to belongs_to. It seems like Rails won't let you do it the other way... or am I missing something?

Comment: Well semantically the form you wish to create is saying it has_one user so you should probably add that association to the model. (I have modified my example above). But it should not affect any code or data anywhere else in your application by doing so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136091/rails-has-one-vs-belongs-to-semantics